# Need a way to extract specific data from Firebase RealtimeDB to Google Sheets

Tags: json, firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database, google-sheets

I'm trying to transfer Firebase RealtimeDB data into Google Sheets using AppScript.

I need a way to extract ID, Department, and Surname strings from the DB while it is received as such from the Logs below.

I use .childByAutoID() which has the following effect on the DB.

My database: 
[image: database]

Desired result in spreadsheet: 
[image: here]

```
function writeSheets() {
var firebaseUrl = "<my-database>.firebaseio.com/Attendees";
var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);


var data = base.getData();

  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));




var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<my-spreadsheet>");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var num = 2;

range = ss.getRange("A"+num+":C"+num+"");

for(var i in data) {
  var values = [[data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2]]];

  range.setValues(values);
  num += 1;
  range = sheet.getRange("A"+num+":C"+num+"");
  } 


}
```

base.getData() reads it as:

```
     {
           "-M4PTaIESKhQZhreHSE6":
               {"Department":"HR",
                        "ID":"1009",
                   "Surname":"Blanc"},

           "-M4PTgaNIE8BDqAcMr5y":
               {"Department":"Accounting",
                        "ID":"1002",
                   "Surname":"Sandler"},

           "-M4PTmOxxNge0Xfe_ez0":
               {"Department":"Creative",
                        "ID":"1009",
                   "Surname":"Tolkien"}
 }

I
```

Logs: 
[20-04-09 00:11:31:653 HKT] {"-M4PTaIESKhQZhreHSE6":{"Department":"HR","ID":"1009","Surname":"Blanc"},"-M4PTgaNIE8BDqAcMr5y":{"Department":"Accounting","ID":"1002","Surname":"Sandler"},"-M4PTmOxxNge0Xfe_ez0":{"Department":"Creative","ID":"1010","Surname":"Tolkien"}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) :

```js
const data = {
       "-M4PTaIESKhQZhreHSE6":
           {"Department":"HR",
                    "ID":"1009",
               "Surname":"Blanc"},

       "-M4PTgaNIE8BDqAcMr5y":
           {"Department":"Accounting",
                    "ID":"1002",
               "Surname":"Sandler"},

       "-M4PTmOxxNge0Xfe_ez0":
           {"Department":"Creative",
                    "ID":"1009",
               "Surname":"Tolkien"}
 };
const out = Object.values(data).map(Object.values);
//or to change order: Object.values(data).map(({Department:dp,ID,Surname:sn})=>[ID,dp,sn]);
console.info(out);
```