# How can i get data from a JSON array in google app script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm doing a request to an API that is successful but i need to get the data of the array returned, below i will put how the array looks like so you can help me to extract the data

```
{ total_grand: 30600000,
  total_billable: null,
  total_currencies: [ { currency: null, amount: null } ],
  total_count: 5,
  per_page: 50,
  data: 
   [ { id: 13998122,
       pid: 1570982183,
       tid: null,
       uid: 5386231,
       description: 'Finish the first part of the RCP mockup',
       start: '2020-03-26T13:00:00-04:00',
       end: '2020-03-26T16:00:00-04:00',
       updated: '2020-04-02T13:25:15-04:00',
       dur: 10800000,
       user: 'Jose',
       use_stop: true,
       client: 'PLA',
       project: 'Training',
       project_color: '0',
       project_hex_color: '#3750b5',
       task: null,
       billable: null,
       is_billable: false,
       cur: null,
       tags: [] 
   } ]
}
```

I want to access to the user,project,tags,client,start,end and description so i can put it in my SpreadSheet. How can i do that?

***This is how i do the request and how i try to access to the data in the array in my variable `togglData`***

```js
for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
    var listProjects = projects[i];
    var reportURL = baseURL + '/reports/api/v2/details' + params;
    var reportFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(reportURL, options);
    var togglReport = JSON.parse(reportFetch.getContentText());
    var togglData = togglReport["data"]["user"];
    Logger.log(togglReport);
  }
```

Comment: 1.Provide `console.log(togglReport)` or  ``console.log(JSON.stringify(togglReport))`` instead. Logger  doesn't provide accurate logs(`=` is not valid json; strings should be quoted). 2. Make sure your json is valid. You can hide sensitive details by changing them instead of adding `...`. 3. Is there anything you've tried to mould the data to a 2D array, the format required by Google sheets' `setValues`?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61105316/) for example.

Comment: What makes you think that? `console.log` has been supported in apps script for years now.

Comment: Because the `console.log` never printed anything when i put in my scripts so i don't know if i need to do something else to make it work, that's why when i'm programming in GAS i avoid the `console.log` in my scripts and use `Logger.log` instead @TheMaster

Comment: @TheMaster i only have one month programming in GAS i'm very new at this ,can you see my updated question?

Comment: Are you on v8? See [upgrade to modern faster V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime).  If  you don't want to upgrade, and console logs aren't visible, you need to see it in view>stackdriver logging. About your update, it's partly valid. it's not complete. All brackets should be closed : All brackets should be paired. `[ {` should be closed with `}]`. See how it ends with a `,`. It shouldn't

Comment: Yes i did just put it on v8, console.log is now working  the array i put above is the one i'm getting now @TheMaster

Comment: @TheMaster i did just paste all, even with the last part that is the same as you said with the brackets

Comment: Your json is missing *project,tags*?

Comment: @TheMaster no sorry is there in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Range.setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) is used to the set data as a **two dimensional array** to the sheet. Using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [for...of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of),  It's possible to mould the data to a 2D array.

```js
const togglReport = {
  total_grand: 30600000,
  total_billable: null,
  total_currencies: [{ currency: null, amount: null }],
  total_count: 5,
  per_page: 50,
  data: [
    {
      id: 13998122,
      pid: 1570982183,
      tid: null,
      uid: 5386231,
      description: 'Finish the first part of the RCP mockup',
      start: '2020-03-26T13:00:00-04:00',
      end: '2020-03-26T16:00:00-04:00',
      updated: '2020-04-02T13:25:15-04:00',
      dur: 10800000,
      user: 'Jose',
      use_stop: true,
      client: 'PLA',
      project: 'Training',
      project_color: '0',
      project_hex_color: '#3750b5',
      task: null,
      billable: null,
      is_billable: false,
      cur: null,
      tags: [],
    },
  ],
};
const out = [];
for (const {
  user,
  project,
  tags,
  client,
  start,
  end,
  description,
} of togglReport.data) {
  //We're looping over togglReport.data and not togglReport
  out.push([user, project, tags.join(), client, start, end, description]);
}
console.log(out);
//SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets[0].getRange(1,1, out.length, out[0].length).setValues(out);
```

Comment: Thanks sorry for the inconvenient