# How do I Map API response to Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, javascript-objects

I am not really a tech person but been trying to learn code in JavaScript as I stay at home and decided to try it on API. I have been able to successfully make an API call and saved the response in an array but finding it a challenge to set the results to google sheet. I will appreciate any help with this. Here is my code.

API Call:

```
var call_token = 'token';
var endpoint =  'projects?'; 
var call_url = 'url'
var pages = 2500



function get_All_Projects() {

var options = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + call_token
    }
  };
var url = call_url + endpoint +'auth='+ call_token + pages
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options); 
var info= JSON.parse(response); 
var content = info.data;

var project_arr=[];
var identity={}

if(content.length > 0 ){

for (var i = 0; i<content.length; i++) {


      identity.Project_ID=content[i].id
      identity.Project_Name=content[i].name
      identity.Project_Start_Date=content[i].starts_at
      identity.Project_End_Date=content[i].ends_at
      identity.Project_Status=content[i].project_state

 project_arr.push(identity)

   return (identity);
 Logger.log(project_arr)

 }


 }


}
```

And this where I am having a challenge passing it to google sheet. I get no error but I don see data being appended to the sheet.

```
function getSheet() {

    var info = get_All_Projects()
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    for (var j = 0; j < info.length; j++) {

        sheet.getRange(2 + j, 1).setValue(info[j].Project_Status);
        sheet.getRange(2 + j, 2).setValue(info[j].Project_End_Date);
        sheet.getRange(2 + j, 3).setValue(info[j].Project_Start_Date);
        sheet.getRange(2 + j, 4).setValue(info[j].Project_ID);
        sheet.getRange(2 + j, 5).setValue(info[j].Project_Name);

    }

}
```

Sample response from POSTMAN

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": 1800301,
            "name": "TEST Project ONE",
            "ends_at": "2020-06-30",
            "starts_at": "2017-07-03",
            "project_state": "Confirmed",
            "tags": {
                "paging": {
                    "self": "/api/v1/projects/1894300/tags?per_page=0&page=1",
                    "next": null,
                    "previous": null,
                    "page": 1,
                    "per_page": 0
                },
                "data": []
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1800301,
            "name": "TEST Project4 TWO",
            "ends_at": "2020-06-30",
            "starts_at": "2017-07-03",
            "project_state": "Confirmed",
            "tags": {
                "paging": {
                    "self": "/api/v1/projects/1894301/tags?per_page=0& page=1",
                    "next": null,
                    "previous": null,
                    "page": 1,
                    "per_page": 0
                },
                "data": []
            };
```

Comment: You need to provide sample json. See sample question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61105316/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61159760/)

Comment: You're returning `identity` and not `project_arr`.

Comment: @TheMaster, Thanks. I have edited my question with sample response I get from POSTMAN

Comment: Why are you creating `project_arr`? It's basically the same as `content` but with different names.

Comment: @TheMaster, as indicated in my question, I am not really techy ( Iam in Fiance) and I would appreciate the guidance here

Comment: Doesn't matter what your specialty is.  If asked a question, research it, think about it, give a answer - doesn't matter how dumb it is as long as you do your research. The question in itself is a guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

The `return` keyword ends current function execution. Because of this, what's returning from `get_All_Projects()` is not the array `project_arr`, but the object literal `identity`, with the properties of the first element in `info.data`: the function is returning while in the first iteration (the first time it finds the `return` keyword). This object doesn't have a length function, so `info.length` is undefined. When trying to compare this with the number 0 in `j < info.length`, it returns false, so the code never gets into the `for` loop in `getSheet()`. Because of this, no value is getting written to the sheet.

#### Solution:

The `return` keyword should be used to return the array `project_arr` after the `for` loop has ended, so that it has all data from `info.data`, like this:

```js
for (var i = 0; i<content.length; i++) {
  // Code inside for
}
return project_arr
```

#### Removing useless code:

Right now, you are creating a new array (`project_arr`) out of `info.data` which basically has the same information. To get this, you are iterating through all items in `info.data` and pushing elements to `project_arr`, one by one. It doesn't make sense to do that. You could use `info.data` directly by doing this:

- End the function `get_All_Projects()` by returning `info.data` before declaring `project_arr`:

```js
return info.data;
```

- In `getSheet()`, change the properties to write to the sheet:

```js
sheet.getRange(2 + j, 1).setValue(info[j].project_state);
sheet.getRange(2 + j, 2).setValue(info[j].ends_at);
sheet.getRange(2 + j, 3).setValue(info[j].starts_at);
sheet.getRange(2 + j, 4).setValue(info[j].id);
sheet.getRange(2 + j, 5).setValue(info[j].name);
```

#### Reference:

- [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: Thanks @Iamblichus, This makes a lot of sense now.